Как добавить 2 цены одному товару woocommerce и сделать их кнопками добавить в корзину?
Мне нужно добавить две цены для определенного товара как на скриншоте это и будет являться кнопками  добавить в корзину


Есть несколько вариантов реализации того, что подчёркнуто на скриншоте.
Можно использовать родной составной товар или плагины, добавляющие опции (доп поля) к товару.
Выбор зависит от конкретных требований.

Используйте функцию групповые товары woocommerce:
https://woocommerce.com/document/composite-products/composite-products-configuration/
Напрмер цена для упаковки в 5 товаров или в 10 товаров
если 5 товаров дешевле чем покупать отдельно по одному товару, то нужно указать скидку для упаковки(product bundles) в 5 товаров и так же для упаковки в 10 товаров
